# My website background slider image is not mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My website is not mobile friendly. The problem is with the main banner and menu. The main banner is not coming properly in mobile devices. Remaining things are coming fine.  Kindly give me the solution to this problem. Below is my site link.

http://www.unicomlearning.com/2016/NFT_Con/

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I think you should visit this first
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I for one won't visit a website. You need to figure this out for yourself. As if I'm going to fetch that code and lord knows what the PHP's for.

Comment: This isn't a website troubleshooting service

Comment: @charlietfl - please don't be impatient with the OP; it appears the OP is only a baby

Comment: i think that page is pretty very much for mobile phones and its very long for a pc browser regardless of viewing it on a mobile screen, you need to split this into pages!

Comment: this needs to be resized: http://www.unicomlearning.com/2016/NFT_Con/assets/img/preview/background-img-slider.jpg

Comment: first fix your html code errors, https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unicomlearning.com%2F2016%2FNFT_Con%2F  then fix your css errors https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unicomlearning.com%2F2016%2FNFT_Con%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: @mlegg, i don't believe in `html` validators, my browser game, which has alot of custom tags, wont pass the `html` validators error checking, even if my page has 0 error, and it works away more than perfect on pc/smartphones/old mobile phones(oldest nokia internet supported phones s60v2/s60v3)

Comment: ok good luck figuring it out on your own

Answer (score 2):

People will get frustrated at you if you ask a question without giving specific prior results from what you've tried and the actual code you think might be the problem. That being said from what you said I can try to help you. So the most obvious thing for responsive design is using pixels for measurements is usually going to be a no go. If the header is the problem you should probably make sure all of your width is based in percentages instead of pixels. Also make sure your media queries actually work. Best of luck! Keep in mind for the future people are pretty wary of visiting strange websites and also nobody wants to help when you just give us your project and tell us you need it fixed! Best of luck however!